# Kubernetes changing permissions of mounted volumes

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, persistent-volumes

I manage a deployment of Kubernetes on Openstack.

My user pods mount a `PersistentVolume` created dynamically using Openstack Cinder as their home folder.

What is strange is that if I create an (empty) file with file permissions 600:

```
bash-4.2$ ls -l
total 16
-rw------- 1 jovyan users     0 Jul 16 17:55 id_rsa
```

Then I kill the container and restart it, the volume gets mounted again, but the permissions now have `rw` for group permissions:

```
bash-4.2$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-rw---- 1 jovyan users     0 Jul 16 17:55 id_rsa
```

Any suggestions on how to debug this further?

### Details on Kubernetes configuration

- The volume `AccessMode` is `ReadWriteOnce`, `volumeMode: Filesystem`
- Volume filesystem is `ext4`: `/dev/sdf: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=c627887b-0ff0-4310-b91d-37fe5ca9564d (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)`

### Check on Openstack

I first thought it was an Openstack issue, but if I detach the volume from the Openstack instance, then attach it again using Openstack commands, and mount it using the terminal on a node, permissions are ok. So I think it is Kubernetes messing with the permissions somehow.

### Yaml resources

I pasted the YAML files for the pod, the PV and the PVC on a gist, see https://gist.github.com/zonca/21b81f735d0cc9a06cb85ae0fa0285e5

I also added the output of `kubectl describe` for those resources.
It is a deployment of the `Jupyterhub` 0.9.0 Helm package.

Comment: Can you please update your question with volumes, pod yaml files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because you have configured your pod with `fsGroup`.  It's specified under the `securityContext`:

```
---
securityContext:
  fsGroup: 100
---
```

Whenever `fsGroup` field is specified, all processes of the container are also part of the supplementary group ID. The owner for volumes and any files created in that volume will be Group ID.

Here`s how [kubernetes API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#podsecuritycontext-v1-core) explains that:

> `fsGroup` is a special supplemental group that applies to all
> containers in a pod. Some volume types allow the Kubelet to change the
> ownership of that volume to be owned by the pod:
>
> 1. The owning GID will be the FSGroup
> 2. The setgid bit is set (new files created in the volume will be owned by FSGroup)
> 3. **The permission bits are OR'd
>    with rw-rw---- If unset, the Kubelet will not modify the ownership and
>    permissions of any volume**.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think you are right, I'll test it and then report back here.

Comment: yes, this works, however I need that option because the home volume is owned by `root:users` and if I disable that option the user cannot write to its home folder. Anyway it is really helpful to know the cause.